# Splash Screen not coming on android Adobe Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, adobe, phonegap-plugins

I have tried phoneGap as per the Adobe documentation.

I implemented the splash screen for both IOS and Android platform.

I specified all the splash screen related things in config.xml

IOS it is working good but for Android when I opened white and black screen is coming for 10 to 15 sec then it was pointing to index.html.

It's not at all showing up the splash screen.

here my config file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myapp.app" version="1.0.0" android-versionCode="2"  ios-CFBundleVersion="0.1.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>InsurerCore</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
     Mobile Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />

    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

    <platform name="android">

        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />

        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/splash-port-xxhdpi.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>

    </platform>

    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />        
    </platform>

    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="ShowTitle" value="false"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false"/>
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="100"/>
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>



</widget>
```

[here my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WlZ7.png)

Comment: set `<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000"/>` and try again

Comment: I tried still it showing the white and grey screen

Comment: which cordova version you are using ?